# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat') - Projection.SphericalMercator.js:19

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am using leaflet to display a map and I wanted to place markers onto it. I wanted to place the markers using information I got from an API call from geoNames. However whenever I try to run the program it errors out with this message.
[image]
Projection.SphericalMercator.js:19

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:19)
at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:7)
at NewClass.project (Map.js:938)
at NewClass.latLngToLayerPoint (Map.js:959)
at NewClass.update (Marker.js:149)
at NewClass.onAdd (Marker.js:65)
at NewClass._layerAdd (Layer.js:60)
at NewClass.whenReady (Map.js:1414)
at NewClass.addLayer (Layer.js:119)
at NewClass.addLayer (Layer.js:273)
```

I want to populate the map with markers based on information I retrieve and not have to hard code it.

```js
//Get Nearby Wiki for Markers
function nearbyPOIs(lat, lng) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/findNearbyWiki.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        },
        //Successful Post Code AJAX call
        success: function(resultNearWiki) {

            if (resultNearWiki.status.name === "ok") {
                
                //Create Marker
                console.log(lat);
                console.log(lng);
                console.log(resultNearWiki);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(resultNearWiki));
                var nearWikiArray = resultNearWiki['data']['poi'];
                console.log(nearWikiArray);

                var nearWikiTypeClassArray = [];
                var nearWikiTypeNameArray = [];
                var nearWikiNameArray = [];
                var nearWikiLatArray = [];
                var nearWikiLngArray = [];



                for (i = 0; i < nearWikiArray.length; i++) {
                    nearWikiTypeClassArray.push(nearWikiArray[i]['typeClass']);
                    nearWikiTypeNameArray.push(nearWikiArray[i]['typeName']);
                    nearWikiNameArray.push(nearWikiArray[i]['name']);
                    nearWikiLatArray.push(nearWikiArray[i]['lat']);
                    nearWikiLngArray.push(nearWikiArray[i]['lng']);
                }

                console.log(nearWikiLatArray);
                console.log(nearWikiTypeNameArray);
                console.log(nearWikiNameArray);
                
                for (i = 0; i < nearWikiArray.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(nearWikiLatArray[i], nearWikiLngArray[i], nearWikiNameArray[i], nearWikiTypeNameArray[i]);
                } //When this commented out it works fine (doesn't plot still) but the rest of the code works as intended

                markerLayerGroup.addTo(map);
                
            }
        },
        //Error in Post Code Call
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);
            console.log(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
};
```

Get POIs
<?php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url='http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPOIsOSMJSON?lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] .'&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&maxRows=15&radius=1&username=username';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode;

echo json_encode($output);
```

?>

I tried swapping out the for loop in the POIs call with a switch case and tried setting the data to global variables for which to call on later but neither work. When I type in the url with the data I want, it has the data I am trying to retrieve, the data is also printed to the console, it just won't let me access it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Minimal** example, please. Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , and start debugging and dissecting your code to isolate the issue.

Comment: Please do not post personal info like usernames and api keys on the forums, someone may abuse them.